# Mulesoft Database Connector issue . How to connect with MS SQL from MuleSoft?

Tags: .net, sql-server, salesforce

I am trying to establish connection between MuleSoft and MS SQL server. This is not working at all and connection is not getting established. The ms sql database is using windows authentication. What should be a proper connector configuration / Database Url ? I am trying to use this driver: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver and using sqljdbc42.jar. We are new to MuleSoft. Please help.

Comment: Please show your attempts so far to solve the problem.

Comment: some questions to help us understand better your issue: 1) Do you have your DB services running?
2) Can you please share some logs or the error code your are having?
3) Please share more information about your environment. I was having the same issue and it was because my PC had the ports close. Try opening them (The ones you need ofcourse).

Answer (score 0):

Check if the MS SQL default port "3306" is open in your system to talk to the DB.

I had the similar issue where we were unable to connect because the port was not open.

Comment: 3306 is the port for MySQL or MariaDB, not MS SQL Server.  MS SQL Server's typical port is 1433.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have below configurations in your database connector:

1. Create Generic Database Configurations
2. in configurations, Under General tab select Databse URL and provide
   below: `jdbc:sqlserver://${mssql.server}:${mssql.port};databaseName=${mssql.database};user=${mssql.user};password=${mssql.password` provide the details according to your server. If you dont know the server and port, then run `select distinct local_net_address, local_tcp_port from sys.dm_exec_connections where local_net_address is not null` query in database. It will return server name and port for you. usually port is 1433.
3. Make sure jar file for jdbc is present in reference library.
4. Test Connection. It should work.